# Getting Magento 2 CMS page programatically fails to render widget?

Tags: magento2, cms

I'm attempting to get data from the CMS pages programatically via the REST api, it seems that widgets aren't rendered correctly.

```
<?php
namespace XXXX\Restapi\Model;

class Cms implements \XXXXX\Restapi\Api\CmsInterface
{
    private $pageRepo;
    private $filterProvider;
    private $storeManager;
    private $pageFactory;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $filterProvider,
                                \Magento\Cms\Model\PageRepository $pageRepo,
                                \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
                                \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->pageRepo = $pageRepo;
        $this->filterProvider = $filterProvider;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function page($id) {
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $page = $this->pageFactory->create();

        $page->setStoreId($storeId);
        $page->load($id, 'identifier');
        $pageFilter =  $this->filterProvider->getPageFilter();
        $p[] = [
            'title' => $page->getTitle(),
            'content' => $pageFilter->filter($page->getContent()),
        ];

        return $p;
    }
}
```

All I get from this is HTML with all the links on the page rendered correctly with base URLs, it's just widgets that fail to render any html.

Comment: Hi GavChap, Did you solve it, i tried your code but i got `{{title: null, content: null}}`

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Does anyone have the answer for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe problem is about store id because it seems that pageFilter doesn't know which store id should be used to render content. Try to use appEmulation.

```
$om = \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation;
$this->appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId,\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, true);
```

Now store is defined you can continue with pageFilter code.